# How to get Appropriate category from another dataframe - one to many match

Tags: python, pandas, match

We have** two machines**, each machine is producing an **inconsistent quantity**.
**df1** is a dataframe for it

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'machine':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'qty':[1,3,5,2,4,2,4,5,5,3,2]})
```

[[image: df1]]

**df2** is the dataframe of the box volume size, also **Each volume size a different size**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'machine':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                    'box_id':['box_1','box_2','box_3','box_4','box_5','box_6','box_7','box_8','box_9','box_10','box_11','box_12'],
                    'volume':[4,5,3,2,5,3,4,3,6,4,8,5]})
```

[[image: df2]]

I want to **add "box_id" column to df1 **to find and match the a**ppropriate box id of df2**.
Like the output dataframe at the bottom.

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'machine':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                           'qty':[1,3,5,2,4,2,4,5,5,3,2],
                           'box_id':['box_1','box_1','box_2','box_3','box_5','box_6','box_7','box_9','box_11','box_12','box_12']})
```

[[image: output_df]]

To explain in detail

add the box_id in order from the top to** get close to the each box volume**(df2) **but not exceed the each box**

For example,
in machine A, first product quantity is 1, but first box (box_1) volume is 4
box_1 can contain the first product, The box ID in the **first column is box_1**

and then second product quantity is 3,
box_1 has the first product(quantity 1), but there is 3 free space in that box
The box ID in** the second row is also box_1
**
third product is 5, also the next box(box_2) volume is 5, so **The third row is box_2**
fourth product is 2, the next box(box_3)  volume is 3, so **The third row is box_3
**
but In the fifth case, product is 4, but the next box(box_4) is only 2,
so** box_4 cannot be used, and the following box_5 must be used
**
When the machine changes, reset the box again and use the next box.

in machine B, first product quantity is 2, but next box(box_6) volume is 3
so box_6 can be used

It's not for the purpose of learning, it's actually produced like this in our factory.
I'm going to do partial automation with this

I hope for a lot of help from experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a more stright-forward way by simply iterating the df1 row by row and placing each item in boxes stored in a list. But I wanted to explore how to do this more efficiently, especially if the box can be very large and could fit large number of items.

So, here we go.

You can first add a cumulutive sum column to df1.

```py
    df1['cum_sum'] = df1.groupby('machine').cumsum()
```

Then you can iterate through the boxes in df2 and put as many items from df1 into the box as possible and move to the next box. If no item fits into the box you don't put anything in it and move to the next box. You keep track of the cumulative volume of items you already placed so you only look for items yet to be placed.

```py
    for machine, df in df2.groupby('machine'):
      cum_volume_placed = 0
      for indx, row in df.iterrows():
        applicable_rows = df1['machine'] == machine  # all items in this machine
        applicable_rows &= df1['cum_sum'] > cum_volume_placed  # which are after whatever we already placed
        applicable_rows &= df1['cum_sum'] <= cum_volume_placed + row.volume  # which fits within current box
        if sum(applicable_rows) > 0:
          df1.loc[applicable_rows, 'box_id'] = row.box_id
          cum_volume_placed = df1.loc[applicable_rows, 'cum_sum'].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Wonderful!!!!!!!!!!. You did better than I expected. Thank you very so much